# Saving address into buffer in c

Tags: c

I want to save an address 0xbf924bc4
to an unsigned char buffer
here is what I did but when printing it out it shows nothing

```
unsigned char buffer[700];
char *ptr;
long *addr_ptr, addr;
int i;

addr =0xbf924bc4;

ptr = buffer;
addr_ptr = (long*)(ptr);

for (i = 0; i < 700; i++)
  *(addr_ptr++) = addr;
```

Comment: Let's concentrate on what you want to do. You want to save _the address_ or do you want to save  _the bytes where the address points to_? `when printing it out it shows nothing` Please show the code. How do you "print it out"?

Comment: @KonradRudolph oops, you are right.

Comment: What are you printing out and how? There is no printing whatsoever in your code. What is printed out and what did you expect? _I want to save an address 0xbf924bc4 to an unsigned char buffer_. What is the buffer supposed to contain after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of problems in this code.

- `long *addr_ptr, addr;` declarations like these on the same line are bad practice, the reader might easily get confused over which variables that are pointers and which aren't. Instead, declare each variable on a line of its own.
- `addr_ptr = (long*)(ptr);` is a dangerous pointer conversion, you cannot safely convert a character pointer to a `long` pointer. There are several issues with alignment and pointer aliasing that makes such conversions brittle or plain undefined behavior.
- `*(addr_ptr++) = addr;` stores the 4 byte address over and over again, possibly misaligned.

If the task is simply to store the value `0xbf924bc4` inside a character buffer, repeating the sequence over and over again, then simply use `memcpy`.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t addr = 0xbf924bc4;

for(size_t i=0; i<700; i+=sizeof addr);
  memcpy(&buf[i], &addr, sizeof addr);
```

That's the endianess-dependent version, for a ms byte to ls byte order, you'll have to use an array: `unsigned char addr[] = {0xbf, 0x92, 0x4b, 0xc4};`. Or alternatively mask out each byte of the long and shift them.

Comment: Potential issue: if `long` is 8 bytes, it doesn't go to 700 evenly. Better to use `uint32_t`.

Comment: Maybe also add a `_Static_assert((700 % sizeof addr)==0, "Misalignment bugs will occur");`. And well, obviously, get rid of magic numbers like 700...